# How can I add a column in a pandas dataframe with respect to dates given in another column in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. Date, ABC (which holds some numeric values, and XYZ( also holding some numeric values).
The date is in following format yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss
I want the fourth column to hold values depending on the corresponding date

The idea is that the value from July 2019 to June 2020 is given. Every subsequent year the value depreciates by a factor of 15 percent.
for example July 2019-June 2020 the value is 10
then for july 2020-june2021 it would be 8.5
and then july 2021-june 2022 it would be 7.225 and so on.

How do i get about this?

```
import datetime

for Date, Month, Year in zip(df['Date'], df['Month'], df['Year']):
  if Date >= datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0) and Date < datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 0,0, 0):
    df['Target Budget Yield'] = float(50)
  elif Month < 7:
    df['Target Budget Yield'] = float(50*(0.85**(Year-2020)))
  else:
    df['Target Budget Yield'] = float5(0*(0.85**(Year-2019)))
```

This is my code. I was expecting the first year to have a value 50 and subsequently get 42.5 and so on. I have done other tries too changing the code a bit here and there.

But I get one of 3 output

1. An error saying ambiguous input
2. All the values in the column getting a value 72.27 (which I dont know where it came from)
3. The first year gets the value 50, but every other year gets the value 72.27

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the input and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Target Budget Yield'] = 0.0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    date = row['Date']
    year, month = date.year, date.month
    if pd.Timestamp(2019, 7, 1) <= date < pd.Timestamp(2020, 7, 1):
        df.loc[index, 'Target Budget Yield'] = 50.0
    elif month < 7:
        df.loc[index, 'Target Budget Yield'] = 50.0 * (0.85 ** (year - 2020))
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Target Budget Yield'] = 50.0 * (0.85 ** (year - 2019))
```

Can you try this? I think it should work.
In your code, you're directly setting value for the whole dataframe column, that's why face duplicates. You should update only corresponded row.